# 12" custom flashing for roof?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, flashing

We have a section of our garage that sticks out about 12" from the rest of the house and is flat on top- you can see it in the orange section in this photo.

[image]

The green and blue sections are a boral profit modera stone siding which is varying thickness from .75"-2" thick. In the areas with the red border, we can use a standard metal z flashing, but as you can see the orange areas are too thick to use standard flashing.

We are trying to figure out how to waterproof this area. Our GC has suggested a piece of custom metal flashing which would cover it and have a built-in slope to let the water run off. That piece of metal will cost approximately $2K just for that area.

Can you help suggest other less expensive options? Is there anything off the shelf we can use? This area of the house is not visible from eye level and we really don't want to spend a lot of money on it. I am in the middle of calling wrought iron shops and welding shops in my area but haven't yet found someone willing to take the job.

Comment: Unique architecture calls for unique solutions. The expense in this scenario is not in the materials. It's in the craftsmanship involved with putting it all together in a reliable way. The only possibly less expensive method I can think of would be to treat it like a normal roof and install roof flashing and asphalt shingles.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood, use z-flashing then hot mop and cover with shingle. Or use z-flashing then torch-down mineral roofing sheet. Or use z-flashing then Redguard or other waterproof membrane and tile it... Sloping it somehow would be a **great** idea.